# Issue when creating json object

Tags: c#, json

I have little problem, I have created a JSON object but it is throwing error. Can someone advice please.

```
           int id = 321;
            var data2 = @"{
                'personlize': [       
           {
             'to': [      

                   {   
                        'email': 'amirsal@gmail.com.com'    

                   }
                ],


            }]
}";

            data1 = data2;
            var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(data1);
            var response1 = await client.RequestAsync(method: SendGridClient.Method.POST,
                            requestBody: json.ToString(),
                            urlPath: "mail/send")

I am getting the below error when string is converted to object data1 to var json. I removed other code that not matter to debug the code and to reduce lines to get to the actual issue. 

> Exception: Invalid character after parsing property name. Expected ':' but got: d. Path '', line 1, position 8.
```

Comment: Please show the complete JSON after this line (something like: `Console.WriteLine(date2)`)   (or make a [mre])

Comment: Note that this isn't valid JSON. JSON uses double-quotes for property names, not single quotes. Some parsers may handle it, but some won't (and you shouldn't be surprised by that).

Comment: Friends don't let friends construct JSON with string concatenation... Be our friend :) (and as @JonSkeet pointed out please produce valid JSON - we all have hard time parsing *not JSON that pretends to be JSON* - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426901/is-there-a-canonical-question-on-how-to-parse-invalid-json)

Comment: If you really have to use inline JSON use raw string literals - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/raw-string

Answer (score 0):

When using verbatim string, we can escape the double quotes by putting one extra double quotes like below:

```
string id = "1";
string data = "1,2,3";

string data2 = @"{
                   ""personalizations"": [       
                   {
                      ""template_id"":""" + id + @""",
                      ""data"": [" + data + @"]
                   }]
                 }";
```

Can read more about it here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/raw-string

Then we need to create a Class compatible with our json structure. Following it will be based on the json in your question :

```
public class Personalization
{
    public string template_id { get; set; }
    public List<string> data { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Personalization> personalizations { get; set; }
}
```

and following code can be used to deserialize it in to C# object using NewtonSoft.Json package:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(data2);
Console.WriteLine(result.personalizations.First().template_id);
```

See the following example fiddle created : https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vlo5Vj

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/raw-string would be better suggestion... at least one can read it :)

Comment: Thanks @AlexeiLevenkov you are correct, I added the reference in the post